# Dataweave extract object from array object and create a json request

Tags: dataweave

I am learning dataweave and I am trying to extract phoneNumber, with "contact" being array of objects. below is the sample request.
Request:

```
{
    "contact": [{
            "phoneNumber": "2234567890",
            "emailId": "abc@abc.com"
        },
        {

            "phoneNumber": "2012020004",
            "emailId": "xyz@abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

expected Output is

```
{
  "PhoneNumberList[0]": "2234567890",
  "PhoneNumberList[1]": "2012020004"
}
```

I do not want to use below code

```
output application/json
---
{
    "PhoneNumberList[0]" : payload.contact[0].phoneNumber,
    "PhoneNumberList[1]" : payload.contact[1].phoneNumber
}
```

Could you suggest the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = {
    "contact": [{
            "phoneNumber": "2234567890",
            "emailId": "abc@abc.com"
        },
        {

            "phoneNumber": "2012020004",
            "emailId": "xyz@abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
---
data.contact.*phoneNumber map [$$,$]
reduce (e,acc={}) -> acc ++ {("phoneNumberList[$(e[0])]": e[1])}
```

I made use of

- [.* selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors)
- [map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-map)
- [reduce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-reduce)

Here's another solution which maybe a little better due to Lazy evaluation:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = {
    "contact": [{
            "phoneNumber": "2234567890",
            "emailId": "abc@abc.com"
        },
        {

            "phoneNumber": "2012020004",
            "emailId": "xyz@abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
---
{(data.contact.*phoneNumber map {"phoneNumberList[$($$)]":$})}
```

I replaced the `reduce` function with the [Dynamic Elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements)